# ListView MultiSelect, MVVM and RoutedCommands

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

As far as I know (and I don't claim to know much about this!), direct binding to `ListView.SelectedItems` isn't possible in WPF. I've seen work-arounds involving code-behind which I'm not too crazy about, especially since I'm having a hard time with getting a `DelegateCommand` to work, and decided to use `RoutedCommands`. For the following XAML command binding...

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static my:ClientSearchSection.AddSelectionCommand}" 
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteAddSelectionCommand" 
                    Executed="ExecuteAddSelectionCommand"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

...I have the following code-behind:

```
public static readonly RoutedCommand AddSelectionCommand = new RoutedCommand();

private void CanExecuteAddSelectionCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Commands != null)
    {
        Commands.SelectedClients = SearchResultsList.SelectedItems.Cast<ClientViewModel>().ToList();
        e.CanExecute = Commands.CanExecuteAddSelectionCommand();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void ExecuteAddSelectionCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Commands.SelectedClients = SearchResultsList.SelectedItems.Cast<ClientViewModel>().ToList();
    Commands.OnExecuteAddSelectionCommand();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Where `Commands` is a get-only private property that returns an interface implemented by the ViewModel, which defines all the `CanExecuteXXXX` and `ExecuteXXXX` methods.

Here's how I have it:

```
private IViewModel _viewModel;
private IClientsSearchSectionCommands Commands { get { return _viewModel as IClientsSearchSectionCommands; } }

public ClientSearchSection()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += ClientsSearchSection_DataContextChanged;
}

void ClientSearchSection_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel = e.NewValue as IViewModel;
}
```

---

This allows me to implement the command code in the ViewModel, for example:

```
public bool CanExecuteAddSelectionCommand()
{
    return SelectedClients.Count > 0;
}

public void OnExecuteAddSelectionCommand()
{
    // whatever needs to happen here, I can access my model as needed
}
```

The trick that allows the `SelectedItems` to work is with this property, exposed by the `IClientsSearchSectionCommands` interface implemented by the ViewModel:

```
public IList<ClientViewModel> SelectedClients { get; set; }
```

...and the fact that I'm setting them in the commands' `CanExecute` and `Executed` handlers.

This works beautifully... but is it weird in any way? [How] could it be done better?

I don't want to dive into *behaviors* at this point, firstly because I have no clue about them, second, because I'm dragging a more junior developper into WPF & MVVM, coming from WinForms and inline-SQL-in-the-form's-code-behind, so I'd like to know if this code is easy enough to follow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach looks fine to me. Except i would probably use prefix-casting, to get cast exceptions straigt away if something goes wrong, instead of using `as`.

This can be achieved without modifying code-behind tho. You can bind container's IsSelected property to appropriate item's viewmodel property.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" >
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then you can access selected items in your viewmodel by using:

```
protected IEnumerable<Item> SelectedItems { get { return Items.Where(x => x.IsSelected); } }
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing - turns out I have those "item view models" implementing a `ISelectable` interface so they all have a `IsSelected` property, and with this XAML I can perform that binding at item level, only the designer blue-squigles `{Binding IsSelected}` saying it can't resolve that property.. but it works! Is there a way to make the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` block understand that the view model it should validate at design-time against is that of `ListView.ItemsSource`? (like `ListView.ItemTemplate` does) ...'cause for a novice dev it's not obvious that it works at run-time!

Comment: @retailcoder, yes, you should either set an actual DataContext in Xaml or specify a design-time DataContext (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863099/can-i-somehow-tell-resharper-about-the-type-of-the-viewmodel for example). Normally it doesn't worth the effort tho.

Comment: I meant this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100882/how-does-this-setter-end-up-working-listview-multiselect/19101155?noredirect=1#comment28241704_19101155